# expressjs: typescript: Argument of type 'typeof <express.Router>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'

Tags: javascript, express, typescript, typescript-typings

I am using expressjs with the latest typescript definition file and typescript 2.3.4 from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped.
I defined a router and would like to use it from a subpath as is stated in the official 4.x documentation (`app.use('/calendar', router);`), but I get following error

```
Error: /Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/universal/src/server/server.ts (161,34): Argument of type 'typeof "/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/universal/src/server/routes/login.router"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'.
  Type 'typeof "/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/universal/src/server/routes/login.router"' is not assignable to type '(RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler)[]'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'typeof "/Users/matthias/Documents/private workspace/universal/src/server/routes/login.router"'.
```

This is the router I am using, ommiting the actual code...

```
const router : express.Router = express.Router();
let loginController = new LoginController();

router.post('/signin', function(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {

  ...

  })(req, res, next);
});

...

export default router;
```

... and this is the shortened version of the call to it.

```
import * as loginRouter from './routes/login.router';

private app = express();
this.app.use('/api/v1/auth', loginRouter);
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this usecase just not properly defined in the typescript definition files?

Kind Regards

Comment: I had a related issue and for me the solution was [this post](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3263#issuecomment-331815497) on a related GitHub issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found it, import * as ... seems to lose its typescript information (IRouter, Router)

Solution is to use `import loginRouter from './routes/login.router';` instead

Comment: Odd, I am encountering the same issue and despite me importing it as you have said , the issue still arises

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue by removing

```
export default router;
```

at the end of my router module. I simply exported it where I created it

```
export const router = express.Router();
```

and then updated any imports of the module accordingly.

I don't know why the compiler had trouble with the default export, but I know that TypeScript's default exports are not identical to ECMAScript's default exports.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing silly mistake and waited for a long time to check solution

I was using an `app` property as a method

```
app('/account', accountRoutes)
```

but I need to use `use()` method instead

```
app.use('/account', accountRoutes)
```